# .asciz string in head.S with formatted variables

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel

In the i386 kernel source for 2.6.18: .../arch/i386/kernel/head.S is the following directive:

```
int_msg:
  .asciz "Unknown interrupt or fault at EIP %p %p %p\n"
```

Which is called from an earlier section:

```
ignore_int:
  cld
#ifdef CONFIG_PRINTK
  pushl %eax
  pushl %ecx
  pushl %edx
  pushl %es
  pushl %ds
  movl $(__KERNEL_DS),%eax
  movl %eax,%ds
  movl %eax,%es
  pushl 16(%esp)
  pushl 24(%esp)
  pushl 32(%esp)
  pushl 40(%esp)
  pushl $int_msg
#ifdef CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK
  call early_printk
#else
  call printk
#endif
  addl $(5*4),%esp
  popl %ds
  popl %es
  popl %edx
  popl %ecx
  popl %eax
#endif
  iret
```

The %p usage is not specified in any documentation that I can find.  How does the assembler or run time determine what the print in the '%p %p %p' part of the string?

Comment: I will note that some variation of this section is in all the linux kernel source.

Comment: `%` fields in the format string are processed by `printk()`. It's the kernel's version of `printf()`.

Comment: Assuming it's like printf, `%p` is for printing the value of a pointer.

Comment: "not specified in any documentation that I can find" - How about [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/core-api/printk-formats.html#pointer-types)?

Comment: That was very helpful Mr. Wohlferd and Barmar.  It's been a while since I poked around assembly, so I missed that all the pushing before the call_* business was calling convention behavior.  The lynchpin is that this is setting up for printk, and nothing to do inherently with the idt.  If one of you wants to write it up, I will accept it.

Comment: The assembler itself *doesn't* treat `%p` specially, it just assembles the literal bytes into the current section of the output (object file).  And yes, this is the handle for all interrupts where Linux hasn't installed a different handler.  It runs in an interrupt context, thus having to save the call-clobbered user-space registers (relying on the calling convention to save the others, and `iret` to restore user-space EFLAGS).  And sanitizing DF with a `cld` instruction.